# Using nant to compile LESS via exec

Tags: node.js, less, npm, cruisecontrol.net, nant

I have a continuous integration server running CruiseControl.NET on Windows Server 2012. The service runs as user `ccnet`. I have logged on to the server via RDP, opened a command window, and verified the `PATH` contains `C:\Tools\NodeJS`.

I installed less globally, since I have a bunch of projects that I'm starting to use LESS in, and for the CI server, it makes sense to just have a single instance of it, rather than have to install it into every single project (the projects don't need it to run locally; we use LessJS in development with flags that remove it when not running in debug mode).

```
C:\Tools\NodeJS>npm install less -g
C:\Users\ccnet\AppData\Roaming\npm\lessc -> C:\Users\ccnet\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\less\bin\lessc
less@1.7.3 C:\Users\ccnet\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\less
├── graceful-fs@2.0.3
... etc...
```

I can invoke `lessc` manually:

```
C:\CruiseControl\MyProject\private\working>lessc.cmd Website\Content\MyProject.less MyProject.css
C:\CruiseControl\MyProject\private\working>dir MyProject.css
 ...
06/24/2014  11:52 AM           159,145 MyProject.css
```

But when I try to run this via `exec` in nant, I get the infamous "module not found":

```
module.js:340
throw err;
^
Error: Cannot find module 'c:\CruiseControl\MyProject\private\working\node_modules\less\bin\lessc'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
at Module.runMain (module.js:492:10)
at process.startup.processNextTick.process._tickCallback (node.js:244:9)
```

Clearly it's looking in the wrong place for less. But why? My `PATH` is correct as noted. It works from command line. The `workingdir` attribute is set to the same folder as in the command-line example.

Is there a better way to set this up for a CI scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix the problem by tricking nant.

Realizing that it ran fine from a command prompt, I simply told nant to invoke a command prompt, with the /c parameter, followed by lessc and all the parameters I wanted to pass to it:

```
<exec program="cmd.exe" workingdir="${buildfolder}" failonerror="true">
    <arg line="/c lessc.cmd --clean-css Website\Content\Site.less Website\Content\Site.min.css" />
</exec>
```

Comment: alternatively you can execute a bat file that contains several nodejs app calls.   I like your approach much better, however, because it keeps everything within a single script (nAnt)  [exec program="some.bat"]